# Fetching Firestore document based on react-router-dom param doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am using React, Firestore and the 'Run payments with Stripe' firebase extension. I have this function for creating the checkout session (works ok)

```
const session = await createCheckoutSession(payments, {
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: [
      { price: 'price_xyz',
       quantity: 1 },
      { price: 'price_xyz',
       quantity: 1 },
       { price: 'price_xyz',
       quantity: 1 },
    ],
    discounts: [{
      coupon: 'abc'
    }],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url:'http://localhost:3000/order/'+currentOrderNumber,
  });
  window.location.assign(session.url);
```

After the payment is successful I am redirected to the OrderConfirmationPage (and I pass the currentOrderNumber as a param-> to get it from firestore). This is from the OrderConfirmationPage.

```
export const OrderConfirmationPage = () => {
    const {number} = useParams();

    //const {state} = useLocation();

    const [order, setOrder]=React.useState({});

    

    React.useEffect(async()=>{
      console.log(number)
      const q = query(collection(db, "orders"), where("orderNumber", "==", number));
      const orderDoc = await getDocs(q);
      let orderClone=orderDoc.docs[0].data()
      console.log(orderClone)
      setOrder(orderClone)
    })
```

It seems that it's not entering in the useEffect because I don't see any console.log, just these errors.

```
The above error occurred in the <OrderConfirmationPage> component:

    at OrderConfirmationPage (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:11501:66)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:175507:5)
    at App
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:175440:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:174250:5)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

This one is trying to read the first order attribute from the component.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')
    at OrderConfirmationPage (OrderConfirmationPage.jsx:103:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)
```

Any idea what is the problem? Is it because of that success_url? And if so, how can I use navigate if the payment was successful for example?

Comment: First, you need to add a dependency array as the 2nd argument of `useEffect` (e.g. `[number]`), unless you want your querying code to run on EVERY render. Second, the error seems to be coming from the render body, can you add the code that returns the JSX? It seems to me you are trying to access `email` from `user` while `user` is still `undefined`.